# Delete lines X to Y using Mac Unix Sed

Tags: macos, unix, sed

Command line on a Mac. Have some text files. Want to remove certain lines from a group of files, then cat the remaining text of the file to a new merged file. Currently have the following attempt:

```
for file in *.txt;
do echo $file >> tempfile.html;
echo ''>>tempfile.html;
cat $file>>tempfile.html; 
find . -type f -name 'tempfile.html' -exec sed -i '' '3,10d' {} +;
find . -type f -name 'tempfile.html' -exec sed -i '' '/<ACROSS>/,$d' {} +;
# ----------------
# some other stuff
# ----------------
done;
```

I am extracting a section of text from a bunch of files and concating them all together, but still need to know from which file each selection originated. First I concat the name of the file then (supposedly) the selection of text from each file. then repeat the process.

Plus, I need to leave the original text files in place for other purposes.

So the concatinated file would be:

```
filename1.txt

text-selection
more_text

filename2.txt

even-more-text
text-text-test-test
```

The first SED is supposed to delete from line 3 to line 10. The second is supposed to delete from the line containing  to the end of the file.

However, what happens is the first deletes everything in the tempfile. The second one was doing nothing. (each were tested separately)

What am I doing wrong?

I must be missing something. Even trying -- what appears to be -- a very simple example does not work either. My hope was, the following example, would delete lines 3-10, but save the rest of the file to test.txt.

```
sed '3,10d' nxd2019-01-06.txt > test.txt
```

Comment: I'm not in front of a mac to test, but I think your find/sed is wrong.  I think you want something more along the lines of `find . -type f -a -name 'tempfile.html' -exec sed -e '3,10d' -i {} +`  That worked on the linux machine I have in front of my face.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, or the Mac command has different requirements. Your suggestion did not work. But thanks.

Comment: I'm very confused about what this code is supposed to be doing. The `find ... -name 'tempfile.html'` part will find your output file (and any other files with the same name in subdirectories), not the .txt files you're using as input. Deleting lines 3-10 of it will leave the filename and blank lines, then delete the first 8 lines taken from the first file ... each time the loop runs. Thus, on the first iteration it deletes the first 8 lines from the first file, on the second it deletes the second 8 lines *from the first file*, etc. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: IMAO verbatim wanted to delete lines 3-10 of each *.txt files as they get concatenated into the `tempfile.html`. But as you said, it won't.

Comment: Now that I'm home and have a mac in front of me, I can confirm that the `find` is similar but not identical btw. osx and linux.  I typically avoid the `-exec` option for `find(1)` in favor of piping find's output to `xargs`, which offers more control and is portable.  I would use something on the order of `find ... -print | xargs -n1 -i sed -e '3,10d' -i '' {}`.  It also appears that linux's `sed` does not require an argument to `-i` whereas OSX does.  Sorry to lead you astray.

Comment: Chris, I'm trying to backtrack and just successfully try a very simple example. From:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html
I took the example, "sed '30,35d' input.txt > output.txt", but even that isn't seeming work on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Your invocation of `find` will attempt to run `sed` with as many files as possible per call. **But note**: Addresses in sed do *not* address lines in each input file, they address the whole input of `sed` (which can consist out of many input files)

Try this:

```
> a.txt cat <<EOF
1
2
EOF

> b.txt cat <<EOF
3
4
EOF
```

Now try this:

```
sed 1d a.txt b.txt
2
3
4
```

As you can see, `sed` removed the first line from `a.txt`, not from `b.txt`

The problem in your case, is the second invocation of find. If will remove everything from the first occurrence of `ACROSS` until the **last line in the last file found by `find`** This will effectively remove the content from all but the first *tempfile.html*.

---

Having that the remaining logic in your script is working, you should just change the `find` invocations to:

```
find . -type f -name 'tempfile.html' -exec sed -i '' '3,10d' {} \;
find . -type f -name 'tempfile.html' -exec sed -i '' '/<ACROSS>/,$d' {} \;
```

This would call `sed` once per input file.